# Execute complex javascript in android webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I would to execute the following Js code before my WebView load an URL

```
<script language="javascript">
function nascondi() {

     var divCollection = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
            for (var i=0; i<divCollection.length; i++) {
                if(divCollection[i].getAttribute('class') =='socialmedia'||divCollection[i].getAttribute('class') =='source'|divCollection[i].getAttribute('class') == 'search'||divCollection[i].getAttribute('class') == 'sidebar'||divCollection[i].getAttribute('class') == 'logo'||divCollection[i].getAttribute('class') == 'subnavi'||divCollection[i].getAttribute('class') == 'top'||divCollection[i].getAttribute('class') == 'breadcrumb'||divCollection[i].getAttribute('class') == 'left'||divCollection[i].getAttribute('class') == 'right'||divCollection[i].getAttribute('id') =='footer_linklist'||divCollection[i].getAttribute('class') =='navibox2'||divCollection[i].getAttribute('class') =='box2') {
                           divCollection[i].style.display='none';   }
    }
    }
</script>
```

How can I do? With the usual

```
view.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){"+....
```

I failed maybe because it's too long!
Thanks in advance

Comment: divCollection should only be 1 element. If you are giving the same id to multiple elements you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @Royalty sorry I pasted a mistake, this is the correct

Comment: any suggestion to inject the javascript into the webview??

Answer (score -1):

```
view.executeJavascript("/* your js code here */");
```